# How to append values from a list until a required value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I want the sum of values in a list but I'm unable to extract them as it shows an error when I use the index variable.

```
K = input()           # K=3
a = input().split()   
a1 = map(int,a)
A = list(a1)
A.sort(reverse=True)  # list of in integers by descending order
print(sum(A[:K]))     # I want to use K to print values in A

Output:
runtime error
```

I am unable to use the variable **K** for slicing which consists of the index until which I want to perform sum().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that K is a string, not an integer. Therefore, it cannot be used for list slicing.

Fix this by simply casting string to int :)

```
K = int(input())           # K=3
a = input().split()   
a1 = map(int,a)
A = list(a1)
A.sort(reverse=True)  # list of in integers by descending order
print(sum(A[:K]))     # I want to use K to print values in A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
k = int(input())
list_of_numbers.sort(reverse=True)
sum_of_sublist = sum(list_of_numbers[:k])
```

---

**PS**

It is a good habit to write verbose variable names.

Answer (score 0):

slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

K is a string '3', not an integer.

```
K = int(input())           # K=3
```